# UISearchBar setSearchFieldBackgroundImage issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

So I am trying to set up a custom image for my UISearchField image using the following code:

```
 UISearchBar * searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 44)];
    searchBar.placeholder = @"Search for a tag";
    searchBar.delegate = self;
    [searchBar setSearchFieldBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"search-bg.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    UITextField *searchField = [searchBar valueForKey:@"_searchField"];
    searchField.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

However there is something wrong with the magnifying glass that I have. The results is as follows:

[image]

If you see closely the magnifying glass is actually transparent and not white. Where as in the image I have it is set to white. Any ideas why this might be happening?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what is going on here, but you can supply your own magnifying glass image:

```
[self setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"glassImage"] forSearchBarIcon:UISearchBarIconSearch state:UIControlStateNormal];
```